# Display an random Object from API Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I need to display a random object from an array. The array comes from the API.

```
    <template>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <p class="name"> {{chosenName.title}} </p>
      <p class="description"> {{chosenName.description}} </p>
      <hr>
      <img v-bind:src="chosenName.urlToImage" alt="">
      <p class="author"> {{chosenName.author}} </p>
    </div>

 
    <div class="box">
      <p class="name"> {{chosenName.title}} </p>
      <p class="description"> {{chosenName.description}} </p>
      <hr>
      <img v-bind:src="chosenName.urlToImage" alt="">
      <p class="author"> {{chosenName.author}} </p>
     </div>
     <button v-on:click="choose" id="choose-button">One more time</button>
    </div>
    </template>


        @Options({
      props: {
        msg: String
      },
      data() {
        return {
          artworks: [],
          errors: [],
          chosenName: '',
        }
    
      },
    
      created() {
        axios.get(url)
          .then(response => {
            this.artworks = response.data.names;
          })
          .catch(e => {
            this.errors.push(e)
          })
      },
    
      methods: {
        choose() {
          const chosenNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.artworks.length);
          this.chosenName = this.artworks[chosenNumber];
          console.log(chosenNumber)
        }
      }
    })
```

I managed to display the random object on click. What I would like to have is the object appearing at page load. I tried to put the function in the mounted cycle but with no good result like this ---> this.choose();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to call `this.choose()` in your mounted/created hook after the promise is fulfilled if you want to make it appear on the page load as well. e.g:

```
mounted () {
  axios.get(url)
      .then(response => {
        this.artworks = response.data.names;
        this.choose()
      })
      .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e)
      })
}
```